# The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint in dbo.interests

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, cascade

I am running into a problem deleting related entities from my database. I have a trading application where users can post trades and express their interests in other people's trades.

When a user deletes their account, all trades posted and interests expressed by this user should be removed from the database. However, the latter doesn't seem to work (I am also not sure if the first one works as I don't know in what order they get executed). I get the error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FKq9kr60l7n7h3yf82s44rkoe4g". The conflict occurred in database "dbi438161_i438161", table "dbo.interests", column 'user_id'.

Note: I get the same when I try to delete a trade but then the column is 'trade_id'

I do the same for the trades and roles of a user so I think it has to do with what is in my interest entity. I am using CascadeType.ALL annotation to let Hibernate remove related entities

Lists of related entities in user:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
    private List<Interest> interests = new ArrayList<>();

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
    private List<Trade> trades = new ArrayList<>();
```

Interest entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "interests")
public class Interest {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int interestId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "trade_id", nullable = false)
    private Trade trade;

    private String comment;

    public Interest(User user, Trade trade, String comment) {
        this.user = user;
        this.trade = trade;
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public Interest(){

    }
}
```

For comparison, the trade entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "trades")
public class Trade {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="trade_id")
    private int tradeId;

    @Column(name="wants")
    private String wants;

    @Column(name="offers")
    private String offers;

    @Column(name="date_last_modified")
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="trade")
    private List<Interest> interests = new ArrayList<>();

    public Trade(String wants, String offers, User user){
        this.wants = wants;
        this.offers = offers;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Trade() {

    }
}
```

Does anybody have an idea on what I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `orphanRemoval` to `true` for the following associations:

```java
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Interest> interests = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Trade> trades = new ArrayList<>();
```

As it is stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional):

> If the child entity lifecycle is bound to its owning parent so that the child cannot exist without its parent, then we can annotate the association with the `orphanRemoval` attribute and dissociating the child will trigger a delete statement on the actual child table row as well.

Please also note that you should not use `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` for the `@ManyToMany` association as it explained in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many):

> For `@ManyToMany` associations, the `REMOVE` entity state transition doesn’t make sense to be cascaded because it will propagate beyond the link table. Since the other side might be referenced by other entities on the parent-side, the automatic removal might end up in a `ConstraintViolationException`.